# Invalid dynamic link when using firebase in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, configuration, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am working on implementing firebase dynamic links to handle deep link in an app.

I followed the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create) but it doesn't work.

The steps I did to configure dynamic links (after configuring Firebase with my app)

- I added the App ID Prefix ( Team ID ) in the project settings in Firebase Console
- In Dynamic Link tab in Firebase Console: I added the URL Prefix
- I checked the apple-app-site-association file and everything is fine and I can find the appID
- In Xcode, I added the associated domain in the target ( the URL Prefix in Firebase )
- In Xcode, I added a URL Type also and set the URL Scheme to the app bundle id ( as it's the default for firebase )

I tried to test it and put the URL Prefix in the notes and when I click on, it opens safari instead of the app and the page says "Invalid Dynamic Link"

I tried to remove the app, hard restart device, clean Xcode build folder and install again and it didn't work also I tried to build by release mode but also it didn't work

so does anyone figured out a solution if he went through this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, It worked after some time without making any change.

Firebase may take some time to make the changes effective.

Comment: I just spend 2 days with this issue, but it havent resolved yet

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, and it seems to be related with some unicode in the dynamic link